# How to structure Typescript library with demo site as one single project

Tags: javascript, typescript, structure, typescript3.0

I am looking to build a JavaScript library as **mylib** that provides a specific functionality. The library is in pure JavaScript and is meant to be used in browser. I am also building a demo site that depends on this library.

How do I structure this TypeScript project? My current structure is:

```
src
 +-- package.json
 +-- tsconfig.json
 +-- library
   +-- Library.ts
   +-- sub/Library-Dependency-1.ts
   +-- sub/Library-Dependency-2.ts
 +-- demo
   +-- index.html
   +-- DemoPage.ts
   +-- mods/Demo-page-dep-1.ts
   +-- mods/Demo-page-dep-2.ts
```

**index.html** should ideally load both (compiled bundles) `mylib.js` and `demo-page.js`

I am getting errors in import statements in **DemoPage.ts**

```
// none of the following import statements work
import MyLib from 'mylib';

import MyLib from './../library/Library';
```

I have tried using TypeScript 3.0 project references but that have not yet helped. Need suggestions on best way to structure this project.

Comment: Can you also post your tsconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried using TypeScript 3.0 project references but that have not yet helped. Need suggestions on best way to structure this project.

I would do it as:

```
project
 +-- package.json
 +-- tsconfig.json
 +-- src
   +-- index.ts // library entry 
   +-- demo // Demo folder
   +-- anythingElseNeededByIndex // Folder for more lib stuff
```

## Examples

- https://github.com/basarat/takeme
- https://github.com/formstate/formstate

Comment: Thanks @basarat for the quick reply. From early reading, this is exactly what I was looking for.